# deploy and running with different configurations in maven

Tags: debugging, deployment, configuration, maven

i search a method for Maven that accept different configurations for deploy and debug.  I want to choose different web.xml-file. How to get it?

Greetz,
sheepy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) to substitute values in the web.xml from properties declared in different profiles or in the command line option or you can use property to specify [different web.xml](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#webXml) in maven-war-plugin configuration.